# What kind of Op Amp configuration is this?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image]

I am trying to understand the circuit that is a part of a sensor module. I don't know what exactly it is doing. The Vin signal is an AC signal.

Comment: It's a low-pass, as high frequencies are fed back to the input through C4, and R6 avoids integration over C4. R4 and R7 are creating a virtual ground of Vcc/2 at the noninverting input.

Comment: Ahh okay. What is the purpose of a virtual ground?

Comment: To add a bias to something, in this case the half supply bias is most likely because the op amp does not have a negative supply voltage so it can only.work with signals between ground and positive supply.

Comment: It looks like a single-supply [transimpedance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier)

Comment: It is a transimpedance amplifier. The input has zero impedance, it might be for a light sensor to maintain a constant voltage on the sensor. The capacitor is there to cut the noise.

Answer (score 4):

Like drawn, the circuit is incomplete / unclear as there is no resistor (and/or capacitor) between \$V_{in}\$ and the - input of the opamp. That means that the feedback circuit (R6, C4) actually doesn't do anything and the opamp will work as a **comparator**.

Without the DC biasing (which isn't needed if we use a symmetric power supply) that would look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjVYiy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left is the comparator circuit.

Add one resistor and we get a 10x inverting amplifier.

As mentioned I removed the biasing (virtual ground) resistors R4, R7 to make the schematic simpler. Since I'm using +5 V and -5 V supply rails I don't need a "virtual" ground, I can use the real one instead.

When using a single supply voltage of for example +10 V only then we need to set a "working point" for the opamp. It cannot be ground as the opamp cannot work with signals close to ground voltage (0 Volt) when it does not have a negative supply voltage. So we have to creat a "virtual" ground. That's where R4 and R7 come in, they make a voltage of half of the supply voltage. If the supply was 10 V then that would be 5 V giving the opamp a good working point.

Comment: Why would you need a negative feedback in a comparator?

Comment: @Dorian Well actually the negative feedback **doesn't work** so there actually is no feedback present. Note that the input voltage (- input of opamp) is **forced** by Vin so the output of the opamp can do whatever it likes, it still cannot influence the input through R6 and C4. The circuit would work **the same** if R6 and C4 were simply removed.

Comment: Yes, hard to guess without knowing the signal source. Might be a clipping circuit to.